# How to think about Fundamental Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology

I want to make sure I have the concepts of the Fundamental Groups well. The underlying set is that of the quotient set defined by the loops in the topological space, and the equivalence relation of path homotopy between said loops. Then, the operation of the group would be composing, by let's say two loops have base point $p$, then you get like a figure $8$ from composing the loops, and then you allow the figure $8$ to morph into a $0$, still with base point $p$, so that if the Fundamental Group has more elements, you can keep composing this way?

Next, my other question is about the fundamental group of the circle. Normally I would picture a path from $p$ to $p$ in a circle as unique. But from my understanding of the FG of the circle, a path from $p$ to $p$ that has passed $n$ times over $p$ is different from a path that has passed $m$ times over $p$ when $m\neq n$?

And the only reason you can't do this in a disk, is if supposedly you had a winded loop on the boundary of the unit disk, then you could actually unfold it within the disk, getting to the $n=1$ loop?

Are these thoughts the correct way of thinking about the fundamental group?

Edit: I'm partly asking this because the picture of composition in Wikipedia confused me:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Homotopy_group_addition.svg/240px-Homotopy_group_addition.svg.png
Shouldn't you start with picture 2, then go to 1, and I don't know what 3 stands for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you dive into the fundamental group of a circle, do you understand what it means for the fundamental group to be trivial? What is the fundamental group of the disk?
As for the wikipedia image, they are thinking of any loop in a space as a map from $S^1$ into the space, and showing how, if we have 2 such maps (picture 2), we can combine them to have a single map from $S^1$ into the space (picture 1). Picture 3 is just a visualization of the image of the map from $S^1$ (the loops).

Comment: @cocoahomology Trivial is if there is only one element. So only one equivalence class of loops?  The fundamental group of the disk would be the trivial group with one element, since you can continuously deform a loop (based at $p$) to any other loop (based at $p$). 
At least that's what I gather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that we have to be concerned with more than just the *image* of a loop.

A loop is a continuous function $f:[0, 1] \rightarrow X$ with $f(0)=f(1)=p$.

Consider the constant loop $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by  $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. This is certainly a different loop than the one which traverses halfway around the circle and then comes back: $g(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{2\pi ix} & x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\\
e^{2\pi i\left(1-x\right)} & x\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]
\end{cases}$.

But $f$ and $g$ are *homotopic* through the homotopy $H:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by $H(x, t) = \begin{cases}
e^{2\pi ixt} & x\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\\
e^{2\pi i\left(1-x\right)t} & x\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]
\end{cases}$, so they are in the same equivalence class and represent the same element in $\pi_1(S^1)$.

It should be easy to see that similarly $f$ is also homotopic to a loop which traverses around the circle *twice* and then comes back. This loop "passes" the basepoint more than once but is homotopic to the constant map. So the number of times that the basepoint is in the image of the loop is not enough to determine the equivalence class of the loop.

You are correct in stating that any loop which traverses around the circle *exactly* $n$ times will not be homotopic to a loop which traverses it *exactly* $m$ times, with $n\neq m$ (where the loop is not allowed to "backtrack" like the previous examples) , but this takes some work to show.

I think I misinterpreted your question but still posting this in case it is helpful at all.

Comment: Yeah, you understood my question correctly, in the sense that I was asking for people to see errors in my reasoning. I asked a similar question elsewhere, and you and another person noted that indeed I was looking at path homotopy as the image uniquely, instead of the function itself. Which is why I was finding the circle so counter-intuitive. Since that's the same error some one else found, I think the rest of my reasoning is correct. And I did find your response helpful, since it raised some other situations I hadn't considered. Thanks a lot!